# Piping readers and writers without threads

Tags: java

I have a kind of impedance mismatch between readers and writers and currently can't come up with an efficient and simple solution. There's an external method that accepts a `Reader` and expects to read CSV from it. There's my converter method that takes a file and a `Writer` and outputs CSV. They're wired up like this

```
void convertFile(String filename, Writer w);

void copyIn(Reader r);

Writer pw = new PipedWriter();
Reader pr = new PipedReader(pw);
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable {
  override void run() { 
    convertFile("data.dat", pw);
    pw.close();
  }
});
t.start();
copyIn(pr);
t.join();
```

This introduces all kinds of problems with exception handling. Any ideas for simpler solution?

Comment: Well, as evident from the code, that's exactly what I'm using. But this setup doesn't work without threads. `copyIn` will block when the reader is empty, and `write` in `convertFile` will block when `PipedWriter`s buffer is full.

Comment: Sorry, my vision seemed to be blurry. I have removed my comment ...

Comment: I have solved such an issue in the past by using ByteArrayInputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream (which can be wrapped in Readers/Writers). But is has as drawback that the entire contents of your CSV file will be loaded in memory.

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter reading it into memory is not an option, files are up to ten gigabytes in size. I guess I have to re-implement conversion procedure, so a `read` issued to `ConvertingReader` will read a portion of a file, convert it to CSV and return it. Though managing buffers will be a huge PITA.